# Creating generic list of type object and adding a string

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create a Generic list that will hold any type of items that inherits from Object(I assume every object is of type object).

But, in the case below, when I try to add a String(Inherits from Object), it shows a error in Eclipse

```
Error:-The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Object) in the type List<capture#1-of ? extends Object> is not applicable for the arguments (String)


List<? extends Object> alist = new ArrayList<Object>();
alist.add("USA");
```

Can someone explain why I get this error?

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that `<? extends Object>` could represent any subclass of `Object`, which is probably not related to `String`.  It could be `List<Integer>`.

```
List<? extends Object> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // works
alist.add("USA");  // Should you be allowed to do this?  No!
```

For type safety, you should not be able to perform such an `add` operation.  For this reason, this operation is disallowed.

The workaround is to eliminate the wildcard in the declaration of the variable:

```
List<Object> alist = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Now any `Object` or subclass can be passed to `add`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you are trying is the following

```
List<? extends Object> alist = getList(); // returns a List<Dog>
alist.add("USA"); // would fail at runtime
```

So the compiler doesn't let you add to any `List` bound by wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

The quizzical phrase `? extends Object` means that it is also OK
to add all members of a collection with elements of any type that is a subtype of Object.

Since all types inherit Object you can write just `List<Object>`

```
List<Object> alist = new ArrayList<Object>();
alist.add("USA");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `<? super String>` to add strings or any of it's superclasses to the list iirc.  Or just `<?>` for anything.

See Lower Bounded Wildcards: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html

Answer (score 0):

Your case is another example where the Effective Java's **PECS mnemonic** may help.

Your `alist` is a consumer, meaning you want it to (consume) have new objects added to it. From PECS, then, you should use `Collection<? super Thing>`:

```
List<? super Object> alist = new ArrayList<Object>();
alist.add("USA");
```

This way, you'll always be able to `.add()` any `Object` into `alist`. (And because `"USA"` is an `Object`, you can add it with no problems.)

Note that, using `super` in your type...

```
List<? super Object> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // notice <Integer> here
alist.add("USA");
```

...the first line will rightfully yield an error, as `Integer` is not a supertype of `Object`.

Of course, it is natural how this is a little confusing because `Object` has no superclass, and no class is superclass of `Object`. Due to that, effectively, the only  possible right side for the `List<? super Object> alist =` assignment is a `List<Object>` (or any class implementing `List`, due to polymorphism).

[Read more about PECS here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs).

Read the PECS explanation from the [book Effective Java here](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=Java%20PECS%20mnemonic&source=bl&ots=yYKfPio_S4&sig=xPt211WmFn9SGFcfGOiqeotFmz4&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=MHBMUqaLLIi49QTd64CACw&ved=0CE0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Java%20PECS%20mnemonic&f=false).